# On Line banking log-in problem

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

For the past few weeks (now mid September 2021) I have been unable to log-in to my online bank using Ubuntu be it with Firefox or Chrome. It gets so far and I then get a page with the header and footer close together near the top. Page fresh opens that page (for inputting the passcode) but on inputting the passcode and clicking 'continue' I am back to the header and footer again.Refreshing that screen takes me back the passcode input page.

I am able to log-in under Windows

Comment: Does your on line bank support the browsers under Ubuntu?

Comment: And is your system (and browsers) fully updated?

Comment: And do you have any plugins preventing stuff? Adblocker, cookieblocker etc?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: what browser do you use under windows,and if you use eg firefox in windows do you still have the same problem.just trying to exclude some possible error sources here :)

Comment: The bank know of no problems. It has worked in the past. Last used in July

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20.04, all  fully up to date  on auto,

Comment: With Windows 10, again fully up to date,  works with both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Running Adblocker but that was also running when on line banking was up and running. Will try with it off.

Comment: The pacific problem is that I can get part way through logging into my on line bank and the system them goes no further. I log in, get past the first password input, the bank then send me a six digit passcode. After inputting this and trying to move on to the next page the system reverts to a Header and Footer of the home page, page refresh takes me to the blank passcode page for the input of a new passcode.